# YouTube data API - Handling Client Secrets

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api

I'm developing a server/client application which allows video clips to be published to a users YouTube channel. Our software is deployed onto a server which our customer owns and has control of.

I'm using YouTube's Java API v3 with OAuth 2.0.

My question is - *how should I manage client secrets in this scenario*?

I had considered embedding my own client secrets into the server code but then the quotas and usage would be my responsibility. I'm not sure if it is sensible to ask customers to get their own Google developer accounts and generate their own client secrets...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manage client secrets(as you might already know), include a `client_secrets.json` in your code as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/samples).

In your scenario, it would be advised to ask the customer to get their own account and generate their own client secrets. As you can see [here](https://developers.google.com/terms/), under **Section 1: Account and Registeration**, it says:

> **b. Entity Level Acceptance.** If you are using the APIs on behalf of an entity, you represent and warrant that you have authority to bind
>   that entity to the Terms and by accepting the Terms, you are doing so
>   on behalf of that entity (and all references to "you" in the Terms
>   refer to that entity).

Hence, in this case, it is also important that your client(s) accept the terms and conditions of using a Google API which binds them responsible for any misuse of the API and doesn't involve you. As a vendor/business, it is always wise to stay clear of such things. Hence, asking them to provide their own client secrets should not be something you should worry about. If they are worried about accepting Google's ToS, I'd be worried about them being up to no good.

Hope this helps.